# Python urllib2 HTTPError exception doesn't give desired output

Tags: python, exception, urllib2, http-error

I'm using urllib2 to fetch a page whose contents is a one line number, then comparing that number to the `ver` value. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import urllib2

ver = '1.1'
p = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.someurl.com/text')
try:
    p
    for line in p:
        if line == ver:
            print "Current version:  %s" % ver
            print "Latest version:   %s" % line
            print "It's up to date."
        else:
            print "Current version:  %s" % ver
            print "Latest version:   %s" % line
            print "Needs updating."
except urllib2.URLError:
    print "Error, could not retrieve version number!"
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    print "Error, could not retrieve version number!"
```

I changed the URL a few times to see how the output would change. I added the `URLError` exception as a response to not being able to connect to the page at all, and it works fine. The output is `Error, could not retrieve version number!`

However, when changing `p` to some URL that returned an HTTP 404 error, adding the `HTTPError` exception did not help. This was the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/script", line 1337, in <module>
  p = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.someurl.com/text')
 File "/.../urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
  return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
 ...
 similar error lines
 ...
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

How could I get HTTPError to work? I find it weird that one exception works and the other one doesn't, unless I'm doing something completely wrong.

Comment: `urllib2.urlopen('http://www.someurl.com/text')` is outside the `try/except` block.

Comment: [**`HTTPError`** is a subclass of **`URLError`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPError). You catch **`URLError`** first so you'll never get a chance to be more specific and catch **`HTTPError`**. Change the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I fixed my issue. The problem was, as [Peter Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084416/peter-wood) pointed out in a comment, that my URL was on the outside of the `try/except` block, so all I had to do was forget about `p` and just do it this way:

```
try:
    for line in urllib2.urlopen('http://www.someurl.com/text'):
        if line == ver:
            #...
```

And now the output is `Error, could not retrieve version number!` as expected.